# Swift: TableView with initializer returns nil. Trying to dataPass via protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

rookie here. I created a two tableviews and one gets its data from the previous one. So it has init objects. And I have a view controller where I have a scrollview to display some scrollable images like a catalog. It is just like a menu with categories eventually leading to brands and you tap on the brand so its content comes after.

I do the API call in didSelectRow (for a reason) and use the protocol func. to get images from API to an array then into the scrollview and its subviews. But I can't properly initialize the VC where that tableview that holds the data exists. How can I properly initialize categoriesListVC then use its delegate func?

First VC  where I pass data firstly.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let category = data[indexPath.row]
    
    
    let vc = CategoriesList(brand: category.brand, url: category.url, brandName: category.brandSlugName)
    vc?.title = category.category

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc ?? self, animated: true)
    
    
}
```

categoriesList VC with the TableView with init

```
   init?(brand: [String], url: [String], brandName: [String]) {
     self.brand = brand
     self.url = url
     self.brandName = brandName
  
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    selectedRow2 = indexPath.row
    
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CatalogView2") as! ScrollVC2
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
    dataCatalog() //API call - this works I checked. }
```

And this is how I tried to use its data on the final VC. Would this work? I printed categoriesList here and it gives nil. I probably don't understand something.

```
var categoriesList: CategoriesList?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    categoriesList?.delegate = self }
```

I am trying to use a delegate method in that final VC to use its object to pass data:

```
 func catalogViewModelFromCategories(catalogViewModel: CatalogViewModel) {}
```

I didn't write the whole code to make it as short as possible. But delegate functions and other things are all in the real code.

In dataCatalog func there is only url session and decoder:

```
  if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CatalogViewData.self, from: data!)

                    let catalogFromCategories = CatalogViewModel(images: decodedData.catalogueimages, title: decodedData.cataloguename!)
                    
                   let catalogViewModel = catalogFromCategories
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.catalogViewModelFromCategories(catalogViewModel: catalogViewModel)

                    }
    
                    
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    
                
                }
                
            return
                
            }

            }

        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: share code of `dataCatalog`

Comment: where you declare `var categoriesList: CategoriesList?`  ?

Comment: On the VC where the scrollview is available. it conforms the protocol of CategoriesList VC